# INotifyPropertyChanged and Deserialization

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization, inotifypropertychanged

Given:

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public List<string> _TestFire = new List<string>();

    string _StringProp;
    public string StringProp
    {
        get
        {
            return _StringProp;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_StringProp != value)
            {
                _StringProp = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("StringProp");
                _TestFire.Add("fired " + DateTime.Now);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When you serialize and then deserialize this class, it fires the `RaisePropertyChanged` event, which is undesirable. Is it possible to prevent this event from being fired when the class gets deserialized?

```
var MyclassInstance = new MyClass() { StringProp = "None" };

MyclassInstance._TestFire.Clear(); // Clear property change history

var serobj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject();

var newitem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(serobj);

// newitem._TestFire.Count == 1, the set method was executed
```

Is there a way to get a `bool` value if the class is being deserialized? 
So then I could do:

```
        set
        {
            if (_StringProp != value)
            {
                _StringProp = value;

                if (!Deserializing)
                {
                    RaisePropertyChanged("StringProp");
                    _TestFire.Add("fired " + DateTime.Now);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do what you want by implementing the `OnDeserializing` and `OnDeserialized` [serialization callback methods](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbacks.htm) in your class.  In the `OnDeserializing` method, set your private `_isDeserializing` variable to true, and in `OnDeserialized` set it back to false.  I would recommend doing the `_isDeserializing` check inside the `RaisePropertyChanged` method so you don't have duplicate code inside every property.

So you would end up with something like this:

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public List<string> _TestFire = new List<string>();

    string _StringProp;
    public string StringProp
    {
        get
        {
            return _StringProp;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_StringProp != value)
            {
                _StringProp = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("StringProp");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        // don't raise the event if the property is being changed due to deserialization    
        if (_isDeserializing) return;

        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        _TestFire.Add(propertyName + " was fired " + DateTime.Now);
    }

    bool _isDeserializing = false;

    [OnDeserializing]
    internal void OnDeserializingMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        _isDeserializing = true;
    }

    [OnDeserialized]
    internal void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        _isDeserializing = false;
    }
}
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/QkOcF4

---

Another way you could solve this problem is to mark your public properties with `[JsonIgnore]` and then mark the corresponding backing fields with `[JsonProperty]`, specifying the property name to use in the JSON.  This would allow Json.Net to set the backing fields directly and not execute any of the mutator logic.

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public List<string> _TestFire = new List<string>();

    [JsonProperty("StringProp")]
    string _StringProp;

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string StringProp
    {
        get
        {
            return _StringProp;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_StringProp != value)
            {
                _StringProp = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("StringProp");
                _TestFire.Add("StringProp was fired " + DateTime.Now);
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jc7wDu

Comment: That's extremely helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Agree, can't believe I've been working with JSON for so long, and not hit this problem. @BrianRogers thanks

Comment: I liked the idea of putting JsonProperty attribute on the backing field, this is brilliance. Just for double checking as this question is about deserialization. Is it ok to use this trick on serialization also.

Comment: @JawadSabir Yes, it should work.  Give it a try.

Comment: Useful for sure. I had to modify the first idea two ways: I could see via the default constructor on my class was running *before* the OnDeserializing method. I know that's not supposed to happen, but it is. So set _isDeserializing=true at the beginning of the default .ctor too. Second: needed to set [JsonIgnore] on the field _isDeserializing.